# I want to display sequence numbers based on data value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, databricks

I have a table with values like this:

[image]

I need this to display something like this:

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, this is a horrible data format.  At the very least, you should have two columns for the id range.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string into its constituent parts, then cross join a tally table. I've assumed each ID can only contain the same letter, otherwise I'm not sure what you'd like:

```sql
;WITH  -- This is Itzik Ben-Gan's Tally/Numbers Table
  L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
          FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                      (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
  L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
  L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
  L3 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B ),
  Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L3 )

SELECT
    ID = LEFT(t.ID, 1) + CAST(Nums.n AS varchar(5)),
    t.Name,
    t.Sec
FROM Table t
-- Get position of the dash:
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-', t.ID))) v1(Dash)
-- Get begin and end numbers:
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
    TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(t.ID, 2, Dash - 2) AS int),
    TRY_CAST(SUBSTRING(t.ID, Dash + 2, LEN(t.ID) - Dash - 1) AS int)
) v2(Start, Ending)
-- Get all number in between
JOIN Nums ON Nums.n BETWEEN Start AND Ending
```

Agreed that the format you have is horrible and needs normalizing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

```
/* basic tally table */
drop table if exists dbo.Numbers
SELECT TOP 1000 N=IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1)
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM master.dbo.syscolumns a CROSS JOIN master.dbo.syscolumns  b;
ALTER TABLE dbo.Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT NBR_pk PRIMARY KEY(N);
/* basic tally table */

drop table if exists #temp
/* creating required temp table */
select *, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(id,'A',''),'B',''),'C',''),'D',''),'E',''),'F',''),'G',''),'H',''),'I',''),'J',''),'K',''),'L',''),'M',''),'N',''),'O',''),'P',''),'Q',''),'R',''),'S',''),'T',''),'U',''),'V',''),'W',''),'X',''),'Y',''),'Z','') id_num_range
, left(id, 1) id_char
into #temp
from @tab t
/* creating required temp table */

select id_char + cast(N as varchar(10)) as ID, t.[name] [Name], t.sec Sec
from #temp t
join dbo.Numbers n 
    on n.N between substring(id_num_range, 1, charindex('-', t.id_num_range, 1)-1) and reverse(substring(reverse(t.id_num_range), 1, charindex('-', reverse(t.id_num_range), 1)-1))

/* cleaning tables */
drop table if exists #temp
drop table if exists dbo.Numbers
```

Please find the db<>fiddle demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b0487c076ab408678aac9f0a1e54ac8).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using Databricks, SQL and the `sequence` function:

The setup:

```
%scala
val df = Seq(("A1-A4", "Anil", 23), ("B11-B13", "Raj", 45), ("C101-C102", "Kumar", 67))
  .toDF("id", "name", "sec")

// Save the dataframe to a temp view
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
df.show
```

The main query:

```
%sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *,
  -- Get start num
  CAST( regexp_extract(id, "[A-Z]([0-9]+)-", 1) AS INT ) startNum,
  
  -- Get end num
  CAST( regexp_extract(id, "[A-Z][0-9]+-[A-Z]([0-9]+)", 1) AS INT ) endNum
  
FROM tmp
), s AS (
SELECT *, sequence( startNum, endNum ) seq
FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM s
    LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE ( seq ) x
```

My results:

[image: Results]